# Zend Framework 2 - Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Part - Module Configuration

Tags: zend-route, zend-framework2, zend-framework-mvc, zend-router

I am creating a multi lingual application using ZF2.. and cannot determine how to add a part URL which will form the base of each URL regardless of modules.

```
http://localhost/en/us/application/index/index/
```

I totally understand how to configure `/[:namespace[/:controller[/:action]]]` using DI

```
http://localhost/application/index/index/
http://localhost/guestbook/index/index/
http://localhost/forum/index/index/
```

What I do not understand is how to configure a **Part** route which will be the base for all routes.. In ZF1 I used **Route Chaining** to achieve this..

So I need to configure a **Part** route of `/[:lang[/:locale]]` which applies site wide and then let the module configure `/[:namespace[/:controller[/:action]]]` or any other route necessary..

```
http://localhost/en/us/application/index/index/
http://localhost/zh/cn/application/index/index/
http://localhost/en/uk/forum/index/index/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the `child_routes` configuration key. Take a look at how [ZfcUser configures it's routing (here)](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/blob/master/config/module.config.php#L48): it creates a base Literal route (/user) and then chains the sub-routes (/user/login, etc) onto it via the `child_routes` array.

I think something like this will do the trick for you:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'myapp' => array(
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/[:lang[/:locale]]',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'lang'   => 'en',
                    'locale' => 'us',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => false,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'index',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Then in your controller you could do this to get the lang and locale:

```
$this->params()->fromRoute('lang');
$this->params()->fromRoute('locale');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. what I am looking for.. is it set lang:locale route in my default application.. then it will be the base for all other modules..

ie.. if I was using ZfcUser.. the url would then be /zh/cn/user or /zh/cn/user/login..

Comment: how does the child_routes work across routes across modules.. I have tried to follow as the routes are merged but it is not working as I would like..